# How to Get unique data in SQL query?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have added a my sql query in wordpress function. now i want to get unique data from sql with highest number of "Score".

Ex: This is my SQL Table

I want 2 Results from this table in PHP.

```
     Quiz_name             Quiz_id        Correct_score   User_ID

     KENNISMAKING          1              0               1
     KENNISMAKING          1              33              1
     KENNISMAKING          1              100             1
     KENNISMAKING          1              33              1
     KENNISMAKING          1              100             1
     KENNISMAKING          1              66              1
     ACTIEF VERKOPEN       7              33              1
     KENNISMAKING          1              12              1
     ASSORTIMENT-FRIS      15             50              1
     ASSORTIMENT-FRIS      15             50              1
     ASSORTIMENT-FRIS      15             25              1
     ASSORTIMENT-FRIS      15             25              1
     ASSORTIMENT-PSV       13             50              1
     ASSORTIMENT-FRIS      15             50              1
     ASSORTIMENT-PSV       13             100             1
     ACTIEF VERKOPEN       7              100             1
     ACTIEF VERKOPEN       7              100             1
     PERSONEELSZAKEN       6              33              1
     ASSORTIMENT-FRIS      15             75              1
```

1. Total Number of Unique quiz taken by User 1. (Ex if "KENNISMAKING" appear 7 times so count this only 1).

Output: User 1 Attend Total "5" Quiz (KENNISMAKING, ACTIEF VERKOPEN, ASSORTIMENT-FRIS, ASSORTIMENT-PSV, PERSONEELSZAKEN).

(Note: Only want Number not names.)

2. Total Count of 100% (Correct_score) taken by user 1. from this Unique Quiz name. (If KENNISMAKING has 2 [100% Correct_score] (See line number 3,5) so count this only 1)

Output: User 1 Complete 3 Quiz 100%.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

raw sql. assuming the table name is `quiz`

1. `SELECT count(distinct(Quiz_name)) FROM quiz WHERE User_ID == 1;`
2. `SELECT count(distinct(Quiz_name)) FROM quiz WHERE User_ID == 1 and Correct_score == 100;`

Comment: Thanks for this the result is correct but how to print 5 from this,

<?php $count = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT count(distinct(Quiz_name)) FROM " . $wpdb->prefix . "mlw_results where user=".$id."") ; ?>

Result: Array ( [0] => stdClass Object ( [count(distinct(Quiz_name))] => 5 ) )

How to print 5 using this array

Comment: Don't use `get_results` here, that's for result collection. Use `get_val` instead.